# following HTTPS redirects with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http, https, httpurlconnection

I have a problem when my application make a HTTPS request that redirect to another HTTPS url.

With the HTTP to HTTP redirection I have no problem.

Before that I have used HttpPost and HttpGet requests with any redirecting problem, but in the way as I do it I did not upload files bigger than 2 MB.

The code I wrote:

```
    public Bundle getResponseFromHttpRequest(Bundle requestBundle) {
    /*
     * TO DO:
    httpRequest (bundle):
     headers: bundle
     params: bundle
     url: String
     method: {GET, POST}
    */

    String urlString = requestBundle.getString("url");
    String method = requestBundle.getString("method");
    Bundle headersBundle = requestBundle.getBundle("headers");
    Bundle paramsBundle = requestBundle.getBundle("params");
    Bundle responseBundle = new Bundle();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        if (headersBundle != null) {
            Set<String> nameHeaders = headersBundle.keySet();
            for (String nameHeader : nameHeaders) {
                String valueHeader = headersBundle.getString(nameHeader);
                connection.setRequestProperty(nameHeader, valueHeader);
            }
            //selectRequestFromMethod(method, getRequest, postRequest).setParams(params);
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        if (paramsBundle != null) {
            Set<String> nameParams = paramsBundle.keySet();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baosParams = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (String nameParam : nameParams) {
                baosParams.write(URLEncoder.encode("&",HTTP.UTF_8).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));
                baosParams.write(URLEncoder.encode(nameParam,HTTP.UTF_8).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));
                baosParams.write(URLEncoder.encode("=",HTTP.UTF_8).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));
                baosParams.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramsBundle.getString(nameParam),HTTP.UTF_8).getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8));
            }
            if (method.equals("POST")) {
                //HttpEntity byteArrayEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(baosParams.toByteArray());
                //postRequest.setEntity(byteArrayEntity);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true); //pra poder enviar datos: petición POST.
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",""+baosParams.size());
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
                connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(baosParams.size());
                OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

                outputStream.write(baosParams.toByteArray());
                outputStream.close();

                connection.disconnect();

                Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields();

                Set<String> headerNames = headers.keySet();

                Bundle responseHeadersBundle = new Bundle();


                for (String headerName : headerNames) {
                    List<String> headerValues = headers.get(headerName);
                    String [] headerValuesStr = new String[headerValues.size()];
                    headerValues.toArray(headerValuesStr);
                    responseHeadersBundle.putStringArray(headerName, headerValuesStr);
                }
                responseBundle.putBundle("headers", responseHeadersBundle);

                Log.v("HTTP UTIL CONNECTION","RESPONSE CODE: " + connection.getResponseCode());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                String contentString = content.toString();

                responseBundle.putString("content", contentString);

                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.v("HTTP UTIL CONNECTION","response code 200");

                }
            }
            else if (method.equals("GET")) {
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(false);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(line + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                String contentString = content.toString();

                responseBundle.putString("content", contentString);
            }
            else {
                Log.v("INVALID METHOD",method);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseBundle;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Would you mind explaining it further with appropriate logcat traces?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is I want to my code follow the HTTPS redirect, but it not do so. However, my previous implementation follow redirects with no problem, but I want to work this way to do HTTPS requests by other reasons.

Comment: Solved: there was the behavior of my code at POST request to GAS scripts. Thanks anyway.